# Menu Strip items enabling in runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

My menu Strip is like below.
[image]
while loading time i want to make true for enable and visible property.
Below is my code but that is not taking the preview and print option under the print option.

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem i in menuStrip.Items)
{                   
    for (int x = 0; x <= i.DropDownItems.Count-1; x++)
    {
        i.DropDownItems[x].Visible = true;
        i.DropDownItems[x].Enabled = true;
    }
    i.Available = true;
    i.Visible = true;
    i.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Here it is done by a recursive menthod, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124587/access-the-toolstripmenuitem-child-in-winforms

Comment: @Mohan Can you please provide more details as this much information is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using some [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to:

- Get all descendants (children, children of children, ...) fo a `MenuStrip`, `ToolStrip` or `ContextMenuStrip` or `StatusStrip`
- Get all descendants of an item
- Get an item and all of its descendants

**Descendants Extension Methods**

The following extension methods will work for a `MenuStrip`, `ToolStrip`, `ContextMenuStrip` or `StatusStrip`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class ToolStripExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ToolStripItem> Descendants(this ToolStrip toolStrip)
    {
        return toolStrip.Items.Flatten();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<ToolStripItem> Descendants(this ToolStripDropDownItem item)
    {
        return item.DropDownItems.Flatten();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<ToolStripItem> DescendantsAndSelf (this ToolStripDropDownItem item)
    {
        return (new[] { item }).Concat(item.DropDownItems.Flatten());
    }
    private static IEnumerable<ToolStripItem> Flatten(this ToolStripItemCollection items)
    {
        foreach (ToolStripItem i in items)
        {
            yield return i;
            if (i is ToolStripDropDownItem)
                foreach (ToolStripItem s in ((ToolStripDropDownItem)i).DropDownItems.Flatten())
                    yield return s;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example**

- Disable all descendants of a specific item:

  ```
  fileToolStripMenuItem.Descendants().ToList()
      .ForEach(x => {
          x.Enabled = false;
      });
  ```
- Disable all descendants of the menu strip:

  ```
  menuStrip1.Descendants().ToList()
      .ForEach(x => {
          x.Enabled = false;
      });
  ```

Comment: Mohan, in case yo have any confusion about extension methods, take a look at [C# Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) and let me know if you have any difficulty on applying the solution. It's the most generic solution which you can use for such requirements.