# How to get dynamically created ToolStripMenuItem by name in a Windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

Form2:

```
private ToolStripMenuItem mHelp;
private ToolStripMenuItem apProposToolStripMenuItem;
public void intializecomponent()
{
this.mHelp = new ToolStripMenuItem();
      this.contentsToolStripMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
      this.apProposToolStripMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
     this.mHelp.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[2]
          {
            (ToolStripItem) this.contentsToolStripMenuItem,
            (ToolStripItem) this.apProposToolStripMenuItem
          });
          this.mHelp.Name = "mHelp";
          this.mHelp.Size = new Size(44, 20);
          this.mHelp.Text = "Help";
          this.contentsToolStripMenuItem.Name = "contentsToolStripMenuItem";
          this.contentsToolStripMenuItem.Size = new Size(122, 22);
          this.contentsToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Contents";
          this.contentsToolStripMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(this.contentsToolStripMenuItem_Click);
          this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Image = (Image) componentResourceManager.GetObject("apProposToolStripMenuItem.Image");
          this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Name = "apProposToolStripMenuItem";
          this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Size = new Size(122, 22);
          this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Text = "About";
          this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(this.apProposToolStripMenuItem_Click);
    this.Load += new EventHandler(this.DocumentSpace_Load);
}
```

How to find `apProposToolStripMenuItem` on the form? I tried to remove a particular `ToolStripMenuItem`, but it doesn't work and I can't find `apProposToolStripMenuItem`.

Form1:

```
ToolStripMenuItem mi = new ToolStripMenuItem("apProposToolStripMenuItem") { Name = "About" };
mi.DropDownItems.RemoveByKey("About");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it by name like this:

```
mHelp.DropDownItems.RemoveByKey("apProposToolStripMenuItem");
```

You can also remove it directly like this:

```
var about = mHelp.DropDownItems["apProposToolStripMenuItem"]
mHelp.DropDownItems.Remove(about);
```

Comment: thanks bro.. but mHelp is in second form , first i get in form1 that mHelp how?

Comment: In your code, `mHelp` is private. You will have to make it public and then access it through the reference to `Form2`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the `MenuStrip` or the `ToolStrip` on the form, then you can use [`Descendants`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53813620/3110834) extension method to find all items, regardless of its location in hierarchy of menus and its parent item. for example:

```
var item = menuStrip1.Descendants()
    .Where(x => x.Name == "printToolStripMenuItem").FirstOrDefault();
item?.GetCurrentParent().Items.Remove(item);
```